# Using Data Visualizer with Atmel-ICE with SPI physical interface

Tags: spi, atmel, atmega328p, atmel-studio

I am trying to output some debug strings from an ATmega328P to a terminal window on Atmel Studio using the DGI. I would like to use the 6-pin 100-mil connector of my Atmel-ICE Basic Kit, which I currently use to program the uC.

On my scope I see the ASCII character 'S' as expected:

[image: SPI Decode]

So the uC is doing the right thing. I think that the problem is chip select pin. It is reported on the DGI SPI pinout but I can't use it because it is not present on the connector.

There is an option on the SPI configuration windows of Atmel Studio to "force the startup synchronization on CS". I tried both ways, but nothing changed.

Am I doing something wrong or is it necessary to connect the debugger with the full 10-pin connector to use the Data Gateway Interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made it work. As I suspected the CS was necessary for the DGI to work (as stated on page 23 of the Atmel-ICE user manual!). I found out that this breakout board from Adafruit (SWD 2x5 1.27mm) is very helpful for programming the chip and for displaying data on Data Visualizer. On the breadboard only an additional connection to PB2 is needed using the Atmel-ICE's 10-pin 50-mil connector.

[image: Adafruit breakout board]